Historical Creationism and Books
Do you know of any other books (besides those by John Sailhamer) that advocate for Historical Creationism?

Welcome to the site, submitted an edit to your tags. Resource-request is more fitting. I don't have a source unfortunately.

So you're asking about the "Gap Theory" of creation, but with the creation week affecting only the Garden of Eden, not the whole Earth.

Indeed... is this what you mean by Historical Creationism? It would be helpful to include a brief summary in your Question.

Biblical CreationismThere are now in modernity many scientific based books by credentialed authors that present---and substantiate scientifically---the biblically-based doctrine of the Creation of the universe in a reasonable amount of time historically...as opposed to the unwarranted abiogenesis theories based on time and random chance.  Here are a few:

Stephen Meyer, THE RETURN OF THE GOD HYPOTHESIS
Stephen Meyer, SIGNATURE IN THE CELL
Mortimer Adler, HOW TO THINK ABOUT GOD
Robert Jastrow, GOD AND THE ASTRONOMER
Norman Geisler, BAKER ENCYCLOPEDIA OF CHRISTIAN APOLOGETICS

See also books and research by Jason Lisle, Michele Behe, Robert Boyle, Isaac Newton, Johanne Kepler, Maxwell, etc. There are also popular and professional magazines based on biblical Creationism. (i.e. Acts and Facts, Creation Journal, etc.)
The beginning of the Modern Science Era was marked by a Judeo-Christian framework in which to formulate the various scientific endeavors! The rise of philosophies like Humanism, Materialism, Naturalism, Atheism, etc. have in modernity unfortunately, encroached upon the physical laboratories and academia. However, Creationism has not been without credentialed scientific advocates.
It should be noted that the method and manner of Creation has been debated in the history of the Christian Church, from the Nicene Fathers to the present; BUT God was never left out of the equation. Even now, once hardened agnostics and naturalists, have been forced by their research to reconsider the possibility of an Intelligent Designer...an Intelligent Intervention to move the process in the direction of life...a Fine-Tuner for the creation of life-elements (carbon)...an Immaterial Transcendent Cause...a Mind/programmer of DNA info.
The research of Arno Penzias, Fred Hoyle, Hubble, Einstein, Hawking, etc. has unexpectantly backed them into a corner, and forced them to conclude that a super intelligence has monkeyed with the universe!
Important AddendumThe preceding Answer was given while the Question was a bit ambiguous! Having noticed the book by John Sailhamer, GENESIS UNBOUNDED, with its unique take on Creation, this answer may be irrelevant, and will gladly delete it if necessary. This answer presented the groundwork for believing that science and creation are not incompatible! Which, by the way, Sailhamer is trying to do in the telling of the Creation account.
There is a book that does advocate Sailhamer's presentation: Andrew Perry, HISTORICAL CREATIONISM, Nov. 13, 2013 (Lulu.com).
Beyond that, there are several posted websites that thoroughly examine and analyze Sailhamer's comments on Creation:

https://desiringgod.org/articles/science-the-bible-and-the-promised-land
https://talkgenesis.org/closer-look-at-historical-creationism
https://thenaturalhistorian.com/2011/09/23/the-historical-creationism-o
https://answersingenesis.org/reviews/books/unbinding-the-rules/
https://gotquestions.org/historical-creationism.html

I pray this is helpful in answering the posted question.

Do any of these support Historical Creationism, specifically?

@ Matthew - See addendum to answer by Ray Grant. If previous answer is unnecessary will delete it, and just keep the addendum. Peace.

Does ray grant always talk about ray grant in third person?  But seriously... I ask partly because I deleted my answer after I realized I'd (probably? OP still hasn't clarified...) misinterpreted "Historical Creationism". I'm sure there are other books, but I don't know for certain which promote HC specifically.

@Matthew - I've only found one book that advocates "Historical Creationism" (listed above).  Sailhamer avers that his view of the Creation narrative was advocated in previous Church history. But he fails to list or quote those previous works (according to the research of one reviewer). There is however, some similar attempts to understand the Creation narrative by scholars in the Middle Ages.  Nevertheless, no matter how noble it is to try to achieve scientific "respectability" by modern academians , the SUPERNATURAL CREATIVE ABILITIES OF GOD will always perplex the secular mind!

Jason Lisle is a YOUNG EARTH CREATIONIST! His YouTube videos and books are very specifically YEC. Also, I have found that Intelligent Design proponents such as Myers and Beehee tend to avoid the question of the age of the earth altogether. When asked directly, their answers are wishy washy...generally ID seems to be in favour of the naturalism age of the earth being billions of years.
